# Angular 6 - HttpClient - Catching Error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am currently learning Angular 6 and RXJS through using the HTTPClient.

The documentation https://angular.io/guide/http states that you can catch an error within the `this.http.get` method using `pipe` then `tap` like the example below lifted from the official docs.

```
getTextFile(filename: string) {
    // The Observable returned by get() is of type Observable<string>
    // because a text response was specified.
    // There's no need to pass a <string> type parameter to get().
    return this.http.get(filename, {responseType: 'text'})
    .pipe(
        tap( // Log the result or error
        data => this.log(filename, data),
        error => this.logError(filename, error)
        )
    );
}
```

I am trying to replicate this within my method like so

```
getLeads() : Observable<Lead[]> {
  return this.http.get<Lead[]>('http://localhost:3000/leads').pipe(
      tap (
        error => console.log('error')
      )
  );
}
```

But it's not catching the error within `tap()`, however when using `catchError` like the below it does work.

```
getLeads() : Observable<Lead[]> {
  return this.http.get<Lead[]>('http://localhost:3000/leads').pipe(
      catchError(this.errorHandlerService.handleError('Could not get Leads', [])),
  );
}
```

Is there a reason why the below is not working?

```
tap (
  error => console.log('error')
)
```

Comment: You're only passing the *first* callback to `tap`, which gets the non-error result. That's **not** the same as the example.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of the callbacks for these methods are irrelevant.

```
tap (
   error => console.log('error')
)
```

In this case, 'error' is actually a 'success' callback. If you want to handle an error, you need the second parameter of the tap operator.

```
tap (
   success => console.log('success'),
   error => console.log('error')
)
```

Comment: Neither of those callbacks *has* a name, do you mean the names of the *parameters*?